# CSS3 - Media Queries Not Working (Google Chrome)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have been trying to change the background color of my webpage if the screen size is lesser than 400px. However, the media queries do not seem to work at all. I have this meta tag in place;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to- 
fit=no">
```

The following is the media query I'm trying to work.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

    body 
    {
        background-color: red;
    }

}
```

I have tried using "@media only screen" too. It still doesn't seem to affect the program in any way.

This following is a minimal, complete and verifiable example

```
<html>

        <head>

            <!-- Responsive Meta Tag -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">  

        </head>

        <body>

            {{'Hello'}}

        </body>
```

```
 <style type="text/css">

 @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

body 
{
    background-color: red;
}

}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `@media` query [works perfectly](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/1L0b2y6u/). (resize the frame to any width of `400px` or below and the background changes to `#f00` (red). What are you expecting? Could you provide a working [mcve] to demonstrate the behavior?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu It doesn't work perfectly. The color isn't changing to red if I resize it to lesser than 400px.

Comment: @Raghunathan Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: <html>

   <head>

    <!-- Responsive Meta Tag -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
 
   </head>
   
   <body>

    {{'Hello'}}

   </body> 

</html>   


<style type="text/css">

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

 body 
 {
  background-color: red;
 }

}


</style>

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VttIy.png. Note the right-bottom frame acts as "the page" in that fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@media` query is valid and [works perfectly](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/1L0b2y6u/).
If it doesn't work in your application, it means you have a stronger CSS selector overriding the selector used in the `@media` query. Like, for example:

```
body {
  background-color: white !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body { 
    background-color: red; 
  }
}
```

`@media` query still works, but  `!important` rule has higher CSS specificity and therefore applies to the element.

**Very important note**: `@media` queries ***do not*** increase specificity. They simply tell the browser to apply the rule selectively based on the given condition. But, when the condition is true, the code inside it is treated as it if wouldn't have been wrapped in the condition. So it doesn't have increased specificity.

**Note** Another common reason for `@media` queries "not applying" is when they're tested in browsers with a zoom level set at another value than `100%`.
To reset the zoom level of your browser use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

To see where the currently applying value for **any** CSS property on **any** element in your page comes from (what selector, what stylesheet, what line number), all you need to do is to use a browser developer console (typically opened by selecting "Inspect Element" (or similar) from the context menu, if used on the element).

Comment: In the edit I have made to the question, there are no other stronger CSS selectors. Infact, there are no other selectors at all.

Comment: You're clearly expecting something else. In order to test, you should resize the window of your browser to be smaller in width than `400px`, at which point it changes correctly. How are you testing? Also, what OS and browser are you using?

Comment: I am resizing it to lesser than 400px wide. I am using Windows 10 and Google Chrome. I work with Laravel.

Comment: @Raghunathan, another reason it might not work for you is if you are testing at a different scale than 100%. Press `Ctrl`+`0` to reset your zoom level.

Comment: @ragh, other than that, I'm out of ideas. Try restarting your browser and/or your OS. It should work. You should see what I posted in the screenshot under your question. If you don't, you are clearly experiencing a bug, but it's not related to CSS *per se*. It's related to your particular system + browser.

Comment: The minimal verifiable example works just fine. But when I try applying it to a more complex example, it fails. This maybe because of the previous selectors. I have another question regarding this. Is it okay if I ask you that too?

Comment: @ragh, not really. The way [so] works (in principle) is: I don't help you by building your website. I help you by answering a type of question so I also help everyone else having the same type of question. So you'll need a separate question if you need more help. Regarding this one, I already wrote in the question how to determine what current selector applies the value of the property. You have to inspect the element. It says there where the property is coming from.

Comment: The question of mine is regarding the answer of yours.

Comment: Sure. Ask here in the comments if you need any clarification.

Comment: Is it because of the reason you mentioned that the following doesn't work?

#register 
{
 position : relative;
 bottom : 50px;
 margin-bottom: 420px;
}

@media only screen and(max-width: 400px) {

 #register 
 {
  right : 100px !important;
 }
}

Comment: Nope. all styles set outside the `@media` condition will apply at all times. Additionally, when on screens smaller than `400px`, the `right` CSS property will have a value of `100px` (but will still have all the rest). Unless you have an even stronger selector than the above, later in code. You need to learn how to inspect. To determine where the value is coming from. Without it you're pretty much sailing without a compass. Also, make sure your CSS syntax is valid (you closed all brackets - that's another common reason for rules not applying).

Comment: I've added a few properties to your code to allow you to see what's going on: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/1L0b2y6u/12/ and that it applies.